# Banach space which has Radon-Nikodym Property +Weakly sequentially complete but not reflexive.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I have been trying to understand reflexivity of a Banach space from geometric point of view. I know that a reflexive space has Radon-Nikodym Property (RNP) and is Weakly sequentially complete(WSC) by default. Then there are Banach spaces which have RNP but are not reflexive. Similarly there are Banach spaces which are WSC but not reflexive. $\ell^1$ has both RNP and WSC. Are there any other non-reflexive spaces which have both RNP and WSC?

Comment: Is the James space WSC?  It is not reflexive, and has RNP.

Comment: Nice question. (It follows from Rosenthal's $\ell_1$-theorem that a non-reflexive w.s.c. space contains $\ell_1$ as  a subspace.)

Comment: @GEdgar No? (See my previous comment.)

Comment: The space $X$ constructed [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-145/issue-none/A-class-of-specialL%CE%B1-spaces/10.1007/BF02414188.full) provides an example.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you. That is an interesting reference.

Comment: doesn't fall to far away from $\ell^1$, but an $\ell^1$-direct sum of reflexive spaces both has RNP and is WSC.

Comment: trace class operators $S^1(H)$ on a Hilbert space both has RNP and is WSC. An $\ell^1$ direct sum $(\oplus S^1(H_i))_{\ell^1}$ is another example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good candidate of a non-reflexive WSC Banach space with RNP is the dual $X^*$ of $X$ with property (V) that contains no copy of $\ell^1$.

If $X$ has property (V), then $X^*$ is WSC. $X^*$ has RNP iff every separable subspace of $X$ has a separable dual. Thus, if $X^*$ has RNP, then $X$ contains no subspace isomorphic to $\ell^1$. However, there are spaces $B$ that contain no copy of $\ell^1$ and $B^*$ does not have RNP (James tree space is an example as far as I can remember).

For example, let $A$ be a scattered $C^*$-algebra, a $C^*$ algebra in which the spectrum of every self-adjoint $x\in A$ is at most countable. A $C^*$-algebra is scattered iff it contains no subspace isomorphic to $\ell^1$. Its dual $A^*$ is nonreflexive, WSC, and has RNP.

For a particular example, for a compact group $G$, the group $C^*$-algebra $C^*(G)$ is scattered. Its dual $B(G)$, the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra of $G$, is nonreflexive, WSC, and has RNP.

---

Preduals of purely atomic von Neumann algebras are also non-reflexive, WSC, and has RNP. The Fourier algebra $A(G)$ of a compact group $G$ is a particular example.

Comment: Thank you! I am a bit confused about Fourier algebra. This paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/41292005 says that A(G) has RNP iff G is compact abelian group, but then A(G) is nothing but $\ell^1$ of a discrete group. Also, please give a reference for B(G) if you recall any  at the moment.

Comment: @NewB In the article you referred I can find "$A(G)$ has RNP **if** $G$ is compact abelian". Generally, $A(G)$ has RNP *iff* the regular representation of $G$ is atomic. Theorem 4.3 in https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1993-1147402-7 might be a good starting point. This paper contains probably most of the sources you need in its references list.

Comment: @NewB When $G$ is abelian, $A(G)=L^1(\hat{G})$ so has RNP iff $G$ is compact. When $G$ is compact non-abelian, $A(G)=B(G)$ is an $\ell^1$ direct sum of matrix algebras. There's no interestingly new example until here. Take Fell's group, which is non-compact, non-abelian, but has type $\textrm{I}_{\infty}$ (atomic) factor regular representation. For this group, perhaps $A(G)$ gives an interesting example of nonreflexive, WSC, with RNP.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination. This will get me started.

Answer (score 2):

- Separable dual spaces have the RNP.

Also,

- the [projective tensor product of $L_p$ and a WSC space is WSC](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-02/S0002-9939-03-07052-7/S0002-9939-03-07052-7.pdf),

which gives you plenty of examples.

In particular, the predual of the space of bounded linear operators on $L_p$ ($1<p<\infty$) is an example of the kind you seek (it is the dual of the space of compact operators on $L_p$).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I had found this reference just yesterday. Also, I did not know that space of bounded linear operators on $L_p$ have a pre-dual. Interesting.

Comment: I see that the author have proved that $L_p\hat\otimes X$ is WSC if $X$ is itself WSC, for $1<p<\infty$. He seems to have ommitted the case for $p=1$. What about $L_1\hat\otimes X$? Clearly for finite measure space $S$ and reflexive space $X$, the projective tensor product $L_1(S)\hat\otimes X$ seems to be WSC by an easy application of Radon nikodym property and duality $L_1(S,X)^*=L_\infty(S,X^*)$.